# Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 Get all carts of a given user

Tags: sitecore-commerce, odata

I need to give the customers the possibility to have more than one cart, and I am not able to find a way to retrieve all the carts related to a given customer.
I'm creating carts with this name structure: "[p]cart[userid]storefront", where p is a progressive number.
Then I tried to retrieve all the carts which names end with "cart[userid]storefront", but it's not working at all. I tried:

> http://{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/Carts/?$filter=endswith(Name,'cart[userid]storefront')
>       http://{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/Carts/?$filter=endswith(Name,'cart[userid]storefront')
>   eq true
>       http://{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/Carts/?$filter=endswith(Id,'cart[userid]storefront')
>       http://{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/Carts/?$filter=endswith(Id'cart[userid]storefront')
>   eq true

But all of them gave 500 internal server error.
Could you give me some hint on how to achieve this result or tell me why this ODATA Services are not working correctly?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Experience Commerce doesn't implement full OData funtionality, the philosophy was not to provide an API for complex sorting and filtering.  It's purpose was to provide a simple API for traversing lists of entities and getting specific entities.

What you want shouldn't be too hard to achieve though. Your best solution would be to implement a custom Controller, Command & Pipeline to achieve this. You could look into how the `IGetCartPipeline` functions and leverage this to return the list of carts you require